# What is a word for a person who inflicts self-doubt?

Tags: synonyms

What word would be used to describe someone who makes you doubt yourself and makes what's good about you sound irrational and irritating.

Comment: How about a bully?

Answer (score 1):

## Underminer

Works well:

***Underminer***

> One that undermines ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underminer))

***Undermine***

> To make someone less confident, less powerful, or less likely to
> succeed, or to make something weaker, often gradually ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/undermine))

Answer (score 0):

There are many to choose from. Consider these:

**disparager**

someone who speaks of or treats slightingly; belittles

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disparager?s=t

**maligner**

someone who speaks harmful untruths about something or somebody; slanderer; defamer:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/maligner

**aristarch**

a severe critic

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aristarch

And probably the best of them all:

**niggler**

someone who criticizes, especially constantly or repeatedly, in a peevish or petty way

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/niggler?s=t

Answer (score 0):

An **intimidator**, from *intimidate*: to make timid. ([Dictionary.com #1](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intimidator))

> Timid: lacking in self-assurance, courage, or bravery; easily alarmed; timorous; shy. ([Dictionary.com #1](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/timid))

From the Latin *timidus*: fearful.